# Article before trouble?

Tags: articles

I'm having (a?) trouble with article before the word "trouble". What's the correct way to say, "I'm having trouble doing X" or "I'm having a trouble doing X"?

Comment: Related: [Proper usage of the word "trouble"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/74668/191178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an article before "trouble" and doing so is grammatically wrong. Simply because "trouble" is uncountable and does not need anything to "show" how much trouble.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137212/discussion-on-answer-by-dialfrost-article-before-trouble).